# postgresql subtract between row while column shift

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table like this

```
date            day0   day1   day2   day3
2020-01-01         3      2      1     -1
2020-01-02         2      3      1      0
2020-01-03         4      1     -1      2
2020-01-04         5      2      0      1
```

I would like to subtract row of yesterday on day(i+1) to row of today on day(i).  For example, if today is 2020-01-02 the expected results should be

```
date         day0    day1    day2    day3
2020-01-02      0      -2      -2     NaN
```

the  0 (day0) was obtained by  2 (from 2020-01-01 day1) - 2 (from 2020-01-02 day0)
the -2 (day1) was obtained by  1 (from 2020-01-01 day2) - 3 (from 2020-01-02 day1)
the -2 (day2) was obtained by -1 (from 2020-01-01 day3) - 1 (from 2020-01-02 day2)

I'm thinking of select a particular date and its yesterday then transpose and shift row of the yesterday then subtract between 2 transpose column.  But i think there might be another elegant way to do.  May I have your suggestions?

Comment: Why is `day3`'s value `NaN`?  NAN should probably be reserved for things like divide by zero, which can't really happen here.

Comment: Oops sorry.  I thought it need data from 2020-01-01 day 4 which is unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table with itself if you only need to subtract the values for two dates:

```
select t.date, 
       y.day0 - t.day0 as day0,
       y.day2 - t.day1 as day1,
       y.day3 - t.day2 as day2,
       'NaN'::numeric as day3
from data t
  join data y on y.date = t.date - 1 -- join to the previous date
where t.date = date '2020-01-02'; -- or replace with t.date = current_date
```

This assumes there is actually a previous date for the given date. If there are gaps in the dates, then this would be a bit more complicated.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fbeef3e928cdc5dfbbf4fddeab779de7)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAG()` for your requirement like below:

```
select 
date_,
lag(day1) over (order by date_) -day0 as day0, 
lag(day2) over (order by date_)- day1 as day1, 
lag(day3) over (order by date_) -day2 as day2

from example
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1Z8w9aAR6ftrkXqP2Yovh/0)

**Note:** I have not added column `day3` as no logic is provided in the question. Also considering that there is only one entry for a date in the table